# how to test WCF outside the LAN?

Tags: performance, wcf, unit-testing

I am testing my WCF service with basichttp endpoint using Soap UI and fiddler2 inside the LAN and it works very fast for me but my client outside the LAN claims that It is 10 times slower than my response time inside the LAN. 
- can you give me some hints how I can trace this problem? what could be the possible reason?
- Is there any unit test I can use to implement some calls as if they are outside LAN even different countries, continents?

thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried just testing the endpoint manaully from a box outside of your LAN to see how fast it is? Reasonable ping times? It's prb not something related to your WCF config, and this is not something that you can unit test really.

Comment: I had an opportunity to test it outside lan today and only the first request is very slow but further requests are pretty fast as inside the LAN. I am using https endpoint. could it be the reason? or maybe my client is using proxy. I read somewhere that proxy makes the connection slower. Thanks for your suggestion.